# Parse mysql client version

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I need to programmatically call mysqldump with certain parameters. I try to use either the `--source-data` option or the `--master-data` option.

[There](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_source-data) is the following phrase in the documentation:

> From MySQL 8.0.26, use `--source-data`, and **before** MySQL 8.0.26, use
> `--master-data`

In order to use the correct parameter, I need to determine the version of the MySQL client. But here I face an issue. I ran the mysqldump --version command on different servers and found that the version is not formalized, and is output in different formats on different servers.

On one server, I got the following result:

```
mysqldump Ver 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

And the following on the other server:

```
mysqldump Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.7.37, for Linux (x86_64)
```

The format is obviously different. In this case, the version is in different positions. On the first server version is `8.0.28`, on the other, it is `5.7.37`. Perhaps there are other formats? How do I get the version of the client simply in the `major.minor.path` format?

It seems that the regular expression  `\d*\.\d*\.\d*` is an appropriate option. But on other hand, it seems like an unreliable solution, since there may be more formats for how to output the MySQL client version.

Comment: Execute `mysqldump --help` and search for `'--source-data'` substring. Use it if found and `'--master-data'` if not.

Comment: Ha, thanks, this is a cool workaround

Comment: Write a bug report about their failure to accept "master" (with a "deprecation" warning) until at least the next major version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found three options for how to get the version.

### In Linux

You can find out the version of the installed `mysql-client` package:

```
sudo apt show mysql-client | grep Version

Version: 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3
```

Here the version format is the same for everyone.

The version can be extracted by one line:

```
sudo apt show mysql-client | grep Version | sed 's/Version: //' | sed 's/-.*//'
```

### In Windows

The easiest way is to take the version of the `mysql.exe` file itself:

[image]

more details on how to do it programmatically (c#):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.fileversion?view=net-6.0

### Alternative

You can simply find out if the command is supported by a given version of the client by executing `mysql --help` and check if the desired parameter in output text.